# Type safe redux slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello I have a question how can I make slice type safe and also add possibility to get objects values like in setFilters. initialOptions force me to add everywhere type and I can not depend on interfering of Typescript. How can I solve it? I want to get values in setFilters like

`object['key-name']`

```
type initialOptions = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

const INITIAL_VALUE: initialOptions = {
  recipes: [] as Recipe[],
  likedRecipes: {
    recipes: [] as Recipe[],
    totalAmount: 0,
  },
  recipeTypes: ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Supper"] as string[], // tutaj dodaj czas i typy
  recipeTime: [
    "Very short (~30min)",
    "short (~1hr)",
    "medium (~3hrs)",
    "Long (~6hrs)",
  ] as string[],

  // variables for filtering recipes
  recipeTitle: "",
  filterTypes: [] as string[],
  filterLengths: [] as string[],
};

const recipeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "recipe",
  initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
  reducers: {
    replaceRecipes(state, action: PayloadAction<Recipe>) {
      state.recipes.push(action.payload);
    },
    addRecipe(state, action: PayloadAction<Recipe>) {
      state.recipes.push({
        username: action.payload.username,
        title: action.payload.title,
        type: action.payload.type,
        description: action.payload.description,
        id: action.payload.id,
        time: action.payload.time,
      });
    },

    addLikedRecipe(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      const likedRecipe = state.recipes.find(
        (recipe: Recipe) => recipe.id === action.payload
      ) as Recipe;
      state.likedRecipes.recipes.push(likedRecipe);
      state.likedRecipes.totalAmount++;
    },
    deleteLikedRecipe(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      state.likedRecipes.recipes = state.likedRecipes.recipes.filter(
        (recipe: Recipe) => recipe.id !== action.payload
      );
      state.likedRecipes.totalAmount--;
    },
    setFilterTitle(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.recipeTitle = action.payload;
    },
    setFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
      if (action.payload.set) {
        state[action.payload.filterName].push(action.payload.content);
      }
    },

    removeFilter(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {},
  },
});
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the type initialOptions and let it infer the rest?

Comment: It interfer perfectly but without initialOptions I cant use strings as index type to get object like this   object["key"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extraReducers` option from `createSlice` to better typings and correct inference. Docs says: `it has better TypeScript support (and thus, IDE autocomplete even for JavaScript users), as it will correctly infer the action type in the reducer based on the provided action creator. It's particularly useful for working with actions produced by createAction and createAsyncThunk.`